# Create UILabels within UIView and center UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

Is there a way to dynamically create a UIView with dynamically created UILabels inside it? I'd also like to center the UIView in the middle of the screen.

Any code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "dynamically", but you can create a `UIView` and `UILabel`s programmatically and use autoresizing masks to center them:

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.f, 20.f, 300.f, 300.f)];
myView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | 
                          UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
                          UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
                          UIViewAutoreszingFlexibleBottomMargin;

UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200.f, 200.f, 100.f, 100.f)];
myLabel.autoresizingMask = myView.autoresizingMask;
myLabel.text = @"My Label";
[myView addSubview:myLabel];
[myLabel release];

[self.view addSubview:myView];
[myView release];
```

Comment: Thanks will try this out. can you explain what the 200.f stands for?

Comment: It's just a float value; you don't need to add the .f, I do out of habit more than anything else.

Comment: you actually should stick to that habit. If you omit the "f" then the value will be handled (and possible type-converted) at runtime as a double.

Comment: @till, if you leave out the .f it will be defined as an int which will be implicitly converted to a float, so it shouldn't be an issue in this case; but, yes you're right, it's a good habit to have.

Comment: aye, omit ".f" => int, omit "f" => double.